# Changing the way Visual Studio handles multiple highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2015

If you click on for example a variable, Visual Studio will find all instances of that variable and highlight it. Is there a way to turn that OFF? I just do not find it helpful. Is there a better way than just to change the colors of the highlighting features I do not like? I would like this for C# and JavaScript.

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Highlighting.  Look around some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.  Press F1 if you don't understand something.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I did find that before my post, unchecked it but that didn't do anything - so that is why I posted. With those unchecked, I still get the highlighting.

Comment: @user147372 Maybe it is an extension. Try running VS in /safemode.